# 405 Method not allowed in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, file-upload

I'm using Spring version 4.2.3, Spring boot version 1.3.0.

When I'm using `Advanced rest client` to upload a file to my service I'm getting `405 Method Not Allowed` error.

My Controller is :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadDocXFileMul", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public
@ResponseBody
 HttpEntity<String> upload(@RequestParam("fileUpload") MultipartFile file, @RequestBody FileDTO fileDTO){
    /**
    work with file

    **/
}
```

My FileDTO is

```
public class FileDTO implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -211383758881523704L;

@NotEmpty
private String type;
@NotNull
private Date createdDate;
@NotEmpty
private String clientId;

public String getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}

public Date getCreatedDate() {
    return createdDate;
}

public void setCreatedDate(Date createdDate) {
    this.createdDate = createdDate;
}

public String getClientId() {
    return clientId;
}

public void setClientId(String clientId) {
    this.clientId = clientId;
}
```

My Rest client images are 
[image]

[image]

My Error message is :

```
Status
405 Method Not Allowed Show explanation Loading time: 792
Request headers 
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.86 Safari/537.36
Origin: chrome-extension://hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryFGAn4APIXqrAvDlW 
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Response headers 
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1 
Allow: HEAD, GET 
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8 
Content-Language: en 
Content-Length: 1090 
Date: Mon, 30 Nov 2015 16:00:06 GMT
```

> Note : I'm very new to springs, Please help me on this

Comment: set content-type header to  multipart/form-data, it is set to application/json by default in your rest client

Comment: i've used by changing that to multipart/form-data but no luck

Comment: If you sending file it will override content-type header automatically to multipart/form-data - even if you set different header. Otherwise transport will not work.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is beacause

```
@RequestBody FileDTO fileDTO
```

This maps the body of your request to the object. But you're also telling String that you only cosume

```
consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE
```

And you're sending your request like form data and you don't have a form mapping in your Controller.

I recommend you to seperate it in two methods, 1 with the fileupload and another with you RequestBody, and you can send it json data instead of form data.